# In Extjs4 how to set scrollbar position to bottom of form panel

Tags: extjs4, scrollbar

i am working in extjs4. i have form panel with autoscroll true. I have 20-25 fields with fileUpload field at bottom. When i am uploading file, form's scroll is going to top by default. i want to keep scroll of form as it is on where it was while uploading file. So how to set this scrollBar at bottom of or at upload field section in extjs4

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding the following method to your form declaration:

```
scrollToField: function(fieldId) {
    var field = Ext.get(fieldId);
    field.el.scrollIntoView(this.body.el);

}
```

Here you have a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zZhkL/1/)

*IMHO,it will be better, however, to group fields using tabs or something similar to avoid having a long a and hard to read / fill form*

Comment: thanx sir for reply....i tried this,but its not working...Its still moving scrollbar to top of the form. Actually i had tried as= me.scrollby(-50,-50,true). Its working,but firstly its moving to top and then coming down..i dont want to move it initially to up also

Comment: Did it work for you on the sample? Which version of ExtJS are you using? Did you try to scroll after a small timeout? Can you supply a sample code so I can give a try?

Comment: Just tried again and I found an error when trying to submit the form to nowhere, [try it again here](http://jsfiddle.net/zZhkL/1/), now seems to work as intended

Comment: i am using extjs4. Still its moving my scrollbar to top of page only

Comment: Can you supply a simplified version of your code on fiddle so I can give a close look?

Comment: I dont know sir,how to add code to fiddle and supply here. I can give you my code. I have view with fileupload field as xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        buttonOnly : true,
        margin: '0 0 0 20',
        id: 'add-welcome-upload-logo-field',
    buttonText : 'Upload',
listeners: {
         render: function() {
          this.fileInputEl.set({
           
}); },
         change: function(field) {
          me.uploadFile(field);
         }}. So i have tried in uploadFile function as=var field = me.queryById('add-welcome-upload-logo-field');
     field.el.scrollIntoView(field.el.body);

Comment: Can you paste your **uploadField** method? I wonder if you are doing something that triggers a view update that forces it to render entirely resetting the view.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem into Ext js 4.2 for Ext.form.panel
See the following code. It will helpful to you. 
onRender function call on render event

```
onRender: function () {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            if (!this.restoreScrollAfterLayout) {
                this.mon(Ext.get(this.getEl().dom.lastElementChild), 'scroll', this.onScroll, this);
                this.restoreScrollAfterLayout = true;
            }
        },

  onScroll: function (e ,t, eOpts) {
        this.scroll = Ext.get(this.getEl().dom.lastElementChild).getScroll();
    },

    afterLayout: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if (this.restoreScrollAfterLayout && this.scroll) {
            var el = Ext.get(this.getEl().dom.lastElementChild),
                scroll = this.scroll;
            el.scrollTo('left', scroll.left);
            el.scrollTo('top', scroll.top);    
        }
    }
```